# spring integration rabbitmq messages on ready state

Tags: java, rabbitmq, spring-integration, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

I have a situation with my spring integration with rabbitmq. The messages are sent to the queues but end up in the ready state and one as unacknowledged but the consumer doesn't gets them.

Thx xml configuration is like this:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:int="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
   xmlns:int-amqp="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/amqp"
   xmlns:rabbit="http://www.springframework.org/schema/rabbit"
   xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/amqp
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/amqp/spring-integration-amqp.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/rabbit
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/rabbit/spring-rabbit.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/task
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:spring/prj-rabbitmq-context-thirdparty.properties" ignore-unresolvable="true" order="3"/>

<rabbit:connection-factory
        id="prjRabbitmqConnectionFactory"
        addresses="${rabbitmq.addresses}"
        username="${rabbitmq.username}"
        password="${rabbitmq.password}"
        connection-timeout="5000" />

<bean id="rabbitTxManager"
      class="org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.transaction.RabbitTransactionManager">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="prjRabbitmqConnectionFactory"/>
</bean>

<rabbit:template
        id="prjRabbitmqTemplate"
        connection-factory="prjRabbitmqConnectionFactory"
        message-converter="serializerMessageConverter"
        retry-template="retryTemplate" />

<bean id="retryTemplate" class="org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate">
    <property name="backOffPolicy">
        <bean class="org.springframework.retry.backoff.ExponentialBackOffPolicy">
            <property name="initialInterval" value="1000" />
            <property name="multiplier" value="3" />
            <property name="maxInterval" value="10000" />
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>

<rabbit:admin
        id="prjRabbitmqAdmin"
        auto-startup="true"
        connection-factory="prjRabbitmqConnectionFactory" />

<rabbit:queue
        id="prjSyncQueue"
        name="${prj.sync.queue}"
        durable="true">
    <rabbit:queue-arguments>
        <entry key="x-ha-policy" value="all" />
    </rabbit:queue-arguments>
</rabbit:queue>


<rabbit:listener-container
        connection-factory="prjRabbitmqConnectionFactory"
        acknowledge="auto"
        channel-transacted="true"
        transaction-manager="rabbitTxManager"
        task-executor="prjSyncExecutor"
        concurrency="1"
        max-concurrency="2"
        requeue-rejected="true"
        message-converter="serializerMessageConverter">
    <rabbit:listener
            ref="prjProcessorService"
            queue-names="${prj.sync.queue}"  method="processMessage" />
</rabbit:listener-container>

<task:executor id="prjSyncExecutor"
               pool-size="${prj.sync.concurrency.min}-${prj.sync.concurrency.max}"
               keep-alive="${prj.sync.concurrency.keep-alive}"
               queue-capacity="${prj.sync.concurrency.queue}"
               rejection-policy="CALLER_RUNS"/>
<int:channel
        id="prjChannel" />

<int-amqp:outbound-channel-adapter
        channel="prjChannel"
        amqp-template="prjRabbitmqTemplate"
        exchange-name="prjSyncExchange"
        routing-key="prj-event"
        default-delivery-mode="PERSISTENT" />


<rabbit:direct-exchange
        name="prjSyncExchange">
    <rabbit:bindings>
        <rabbit:binding
                queue="prjSyncQueue"
                key="prj-event" />
    </rabbit:bindings>
</rabbit:direct-exchange>

<int:gateway
        id="prjGateway"
        service-interface="ro.oss.niinoo.thirdparty.prj.gateway.prjEnrichmentGateway">
    <int:method
            name="send"
            request-channel="prjChannel"/>
</int:gateway>

<bean id="prjProcessorService" class="ro.oss.niinoo.thirdparty.prj.processor.impl.prjEnrichmentProcessorImpl" />
<bean id="serializerMessageConverter" class="ro.oss.niinoo.thirdparty.prj.serializer.prjSerializer"/>
```

On the server restart the first one is picked up but on the next call the messages piles up in the queue. Do you have any idea why this might happen ?

Thanks
Daniel

EDIT:

The consumer code:

```
public class JsonEnrichmentService implements EnrichmentService {

@Resource
private UserQueryService userQueryService;

@Resource
private SecurityContextService securityContextService;

@Override
public void processMessage(POJO record) {
    System.out.println(record);
}
```

This will call a new service that has a Transactional annotation to it.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, this is generally caused by the listener thread being "stuck" in user code someplace. Take a thread dump to see what the listener thread is doing.

Comment: I've assumed that and placed a single System.out.println in the consumer code but it didn't changed anything.